# How does code like Nokogiri::HTML('string') work? Is `HTML` a class method of Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I understand that `Nokogiri` is a module and `Nokogiri::HTML` is a namespaced module:

```
Nokogiri.class # => Module
Nokogiri::HTML.class # => Module
```

I understand code like `Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(string)`; fragment is a `class method` defined in the HTML module (or an 'instance method' if `extend self` is used)

I don't understand how I can pass an argument to a module like `Nokogiri::HTML('string')`.

I saw that `::` not only can be used to access a namespaced class/model, but also to access a class method. In `Nokogiri::HTML('string')`, `HTML` is a class method in the Nokogori module, but I couldn't find this in the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTML` is a class (singleton) method of `Nokogiri` module (you are right, you can use `::` instead of `.`). Source code is [here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/master/lib/nokogiri/html.rb#L14):

```
module Nokogiri
  class << self
    ###
    # Parse HTML.  Convenience method for Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse
    def HTML thing, url = nil, encoding = nil, options = XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_HTML, &block
      Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(thing, url, encoding, options, &block)
    end
  end

#...

end
```

You can simply check where is your method located by using [`Method#source_location`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-source_location), e.g:

```
Nokogiri.method(:HTML).source_location
#=> ["/Users/you/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@gemset/gems/nokogiri-1.6.8.1/lib/nokogiri/html.rb", 14]
```

Comment: Thanks for #source_location